# NSMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex cause error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

This is probably an simple problem but would someone nice be able to give me a hint what is wrong in the following scenario, i just do not understand. I have a NSMutableArray "playerArray", which have objects "ZERO", "ONE", "TWO", THREE".

I am trying to remove the object at "row" but it does not work. Could it be so that it returns a immutable array as the exception seems to getting thrown because it doesn't respond to removeObjectAtIndex?

> ```
>  NSUInteger row = 1; // [indexPath row];
>  NSLog(@"playerArray:%@", playerArray);
>  NSLog(@"row: %i", row);
>  [playerArray removeObjectAtIndex:row];
> ```

The result is:

> playerArray:(
>       ZERO,
>       ONE,
>       TWO,
>       THREE
>   )
>   2010-11-21 20:58:46.681 FamQuiz_v2[2166:207] row: 1
>   2010-11-21 20:58:46.682 FamQuiz_v2[2166:207] -[__NSArrayI removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5e3b9a0
>   2010-11-21 20:58:46.683 FamQuiz_v2[2166:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5e3b9a0'

Comment: Show where you create playerArray.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It looks like your array is not actually a NSMutableArray.  Verify it by logging the class name:

```
NSLog(NSStringFromClass([playerArray class]));
```

or, check with:

```
if ([playerArray isKindOfClass: [NSMutableArray class]])
{
...
}
```

Comment: After running the NSLog, above, the class is: __NSArrayI?? Can someone please explain how this can be? In the @interface i have "NSMutableArray *playerArray;" and                                     "@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *playerArray;".

Comment: Well, how did you instantiate it?  Look there.

Comment: THANKS, i did solve this finally. I called an object that returned a NSArray to my NSMutableArray. I am such a noob but learning fast :-)

Comment: `-isKindOfClass:` **will not work**.   Both NSArrays and NSMutableArrays are typically instances of NSCFArray.

Comment: @bbum Worked for me NSMutableArrays returned a log of __NSArrayM, NSArrays returned __NSArrayI

Comment: @deco only started working in recent releases due to an implementation change. Still a very bad design to differentiate between mutable and immutable in such a fashion.

Comment: @bbum I wasn't advocating a design.  Just a mechanism to confirm what his issue was.

Comment: @TomSwift (Nice username, btw) Proposing a solution without comment is an advocation of that solution.   It is always helpful to point out the meta when providing an answer to the OP's misguided question.

Comment: @bbum - agreed to what you say but  I still say I wasn't advocating design as he wasn't asking about design.  He had a bug and I offered a mechanism to confirm the nature of the bug - and it is a valid mechanism for that IMO.  That said, in retrospect, the exception output he shows has confirmation enough what the issue was.

Answer (score 9):

The error message indicates that playerArray is an instance of NSArray, not NSMutableArray.  You cannot call removeObjectAtIndex on an instance of NSArray.

```
-[__NSArrayI removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```